# MySQL empty-string vs SQLite NULL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mariadb, laravel-9

During work on a legacy codebase I started to write some tests.
Tests run with an underlying sqlite-DB.
I've encountered a problem where an empty model-value could easily be stored by a MariaDB (Prod-ENV) or MySQL (Staging-ENV) while it failed when using the sqlite3 test-database.
As the tables are created from migrtions, the same configuration is used in all three systems:

```php
Schema::create('consumers', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->integer('type');
  $table->string('name', 512);
  $table->string('xd_number', 512);
  $table->string('guid', 512);
  $table->string('country_iso', 2);
  $table->string('language_iso', 5);
  $table->string('software_version', 128)->nullable();
  $table->integer('online_count')->default(0);
  $table->integer('download_count')->default(0);
  $table->boolean('is_locked')->default(false);
  $table->timestamp('locked_at')->nullable();
  $table->timestamp('last_online_at')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

The php-code which "produces" the data which is then filled up whith "empty-strings" (maybe, from whatever) is this one:

```php
$consumer = new Consumer();

$consumer->type = $data['type'];
$consumer->xd_number = $login;
$consumer->guid = $this->_createGuid();
$consumer->country_iso = $data['country_iso'];
$consumer->language_iso = $this->_getLanguageIso($request);
$consumer->software_version = $request->input('softwareVersion') ? $request->input('softwareVersion') : null;

$consumer->save();
```

So, this is a fresh instance of the Model and the `name`-property is never called.

I also tried to insert a record with PhpMyAdmin, leaving the name column empty although it is set as NOT NULL.

Even that worked as PhpMyAdmin shows the resulting query with all empty string-columns set to `''` (empty string):

```sql
INSERT INTO `consumers` (`id`, `type`, `name`, `xd_number`, `guid`, `country_iso`, `language_iso`, `software_version`, `online_count`, `download_count`, `is_locked`, `locked_at`, `last_online_at`, `auth_response`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)  
VALUES (NULL, '1', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '0', '0', '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

A model-property which is not set returns, as a normal php class property,  `NULL` when called.
Am I guessing right, that this means, the `NULL`-value is turned into `''` during the save? Probably by the database?

What do I miss, that MySQL and MariaDB both replace NULL by `''` but SQLite tries to insert `NULL` into this column and complains about the integrity constraint violation?

```bash
Integrity constraint violation:  
19 NOT NULL constraint failed: consumers.name
```

```sql
insert into "consumers" ("type", "xd_number", "guid", "country_iso", "language_iso", "software_version", "updated_at", "created_at")  
values (1, FooBar, da55d74c10e1eb31503ec96767268cd0, DE, de-DE, ?, 2022-08-31 00:30:17, 2022-08-31 00:30:17)
```

Comment: Databases won't replace `null` with `''` for you. My guess is PhpMyAdmin or Laravel is noticing that you have `not null` columns and is filling them in with blanks for you. When you write the insert by hand you must include value for all non-nullable columns. Your last insert is missing a `name` field.

Comment: Note, your `insert into "consumers"...` is missing quotes around its string values. It is not valid SQL.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the hint. But both of the SQL-queries are prints. The first one from PhpMyAdmin and the second one from the dd'ed PHP/Laravel-exception.
So especially the second one is more for ..... demonstration ;)

Comment: @Schwern OK, i just tried it via cli MySQL which will obviously not work.
But this does not solve the question why laravel will replace something using MySQL but does not replace using SQLite while the test should picture the MySQL-case.

Comment: @Schwern
"Your last insert is missing a name field."
=> yep, 'cause this is part of the exception raised by laravel where, as the model-property is not set, laravel has no clue it should add smth called "name" into the query.

Comment: We'd need to see a minimum reproducable example of the Laravel code which produces this problem.

Comment: Is it possible the databases have different schemas? The production/staging databases would already exist and may not have been updated, while the dev/sqlite database will be created fresh off the latest schema definition.

Comment: I recreated the staging-db with the same migrations sqlite uses. staging-db sets empty-strings while sqlite cmplains.

Comment: Thank you. It's still not clear to me what is producing the two SQL statements. What is producing ```INSERT INTO `consumers` ``` with the empty strings? PhpMyAdmin? Or Laravel with MariaDB and MySQL? And ```insert into "consumers"``` is produced by Laravel when used with SQLite? Do you, perhaps, have any triggers on the database?

Comment: Can we see the code for Consumer, please?

Comment: I made a Laravel project, added your model, created a Consumer, and I cannot reproduce your problem. The model creation fails as it should. ```SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `consumers` (`type`, `xd_number`, `guid`, `country_iso`, `language_iso`, `software_version`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (42, bar, abc123, US, en_US, 1.2.3, 2022-09-01 19:26:34, 2022-09-01 19:26:34)) ``` [Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/8fb5af6c4c3e139f6e852d908d983afd).

Answer (score 1):

from MariaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/null-values/):

> If a NULL value is single-row inserted into a column declared as NOT NULL, an error will be returned. However, if the SQL mode is not strict (default until MariaDB 10.2.3), if a NULL value is multi-row inserted into a column declared as NOT NULL, the implicit default for the column type will be inserted (and NOT the default value in the table definition). The implicit defaults are an empty string for string types, and the zero value for numeric, date and time types.

This means it is not a Laravel issue, but the database itself. I have the same problem and unfortunately didn't find a solution for SQLite and it doesn't look like there is any.